# xcode error: Parse Issue: Expected ';' after expression

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation

I'm new to xcode and I'm trying to create a sound app. On line: theAudio.delegate = self; I'm receiving the error message:

error: Parse Issue: Expected ';' after expression

Below is a copy of the code.

```
- (IBAction)play:(id)sender {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"winning" ofType:@"mp3"];
    if(theAudio)[theAudio release];
    theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is that the only error that that code gave you? Is this code copied directly from your program, or did you write this code specifically for the question?

Answer (score 0):

Release the audio after play.

[theAudio play];
[theAudio release];

or try this one

```
-(void) myPlay: (NSString *) soundFile ofType:(NSString *) ext{
    if (ext == nil) {
        ext = @"caf";
    }
        //SystemSoundID soundID;
//create and assign soundID to a particular sound
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:soundFile ofType:ext]] , &soundID);
    //AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(soundID);
//To play the sound
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);

//Function to allocate a function to be called after the sound(with SoundID) ends(optional)
    AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion (soundID,NULL,NULL,soundCompleted,
                                      (void*) self);
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the help. I updated my code to look like - (IBAction)play:(id)sender {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"winning" ofType:@"mp3"];
    if(theAudio)[theAudio release];
    theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play]; 
    [theAudio release];
}

Comment: But I noticed the error on line     theAudio.delegate = self; is still appearing. Is it possible I placed the code in the incorrect section?

Comment: Why would the questioner want to release the AVAudioPlayer they've just created? It makes more sense as it is: Release the *previous* player (if there was one), then create a new one and hang on to that.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar build errors in `CoreFoundation.framework`.

- `CFURL.h: Expected ';' after top level declarator`
- `CFFileSecurity.h: Expected function body after function declarator`
- `CoreFoundation.h: 'CoreFoundation/CFUserNotification.h' file not found`

To fix them, I deleted my project's [derived data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-locations_preferences/DerivedData/DerivedData.html). I did this in Xcode under the [Projects Organizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-projects_organizer/articles/about_projects_organizer.html), in the [Organizer Window](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-general/AbouttheOrganizerWindow/AbouttheOrganizerWindow.html), Window > Organizer (Command-Shift-2).

#### Other Things I Tried First That Failed

- Clean (Command-Shift-K).
- `git clean -dXf` (doesn't delete derived data by default), which for me (since I ignore `xcuserdata`), removes:

  - `MyApp.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/`
  - `MyApp.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/`
- Restart Xcode.
- Restart OS X.
- Reinstall Xcode.

I was about to reformat my harddrive and reinstall OS X, which now I see would've worked too. I'm glad I figured out a much faster, more direct way to fix this issue.